# How to get Physical Memory from top -l1 using AWK in OS X Mavericks?

Tags: macos, awk, terminal, osx-mavericks, system-status

I'm using this script for GeekTools on mac and the code below worked on previous OSX versions. However in Mavericks, it returns the error specified below.

```
$ top -l1 | grep "PhysMem"|awk '{print "X"int(($2+$4)/($8+$10)*50)"X"}'

awk: division by zero
 input record number 1, file 
 source line number 1
```

Output before awk:

```
$ top -l1 | grep "PhysMem"
PhysMem: 6796M used (936M wired), 1282M unused.
```

As awk is an uncharted territory for me, could someone please post a quick fix for that?

Comment: Do `top -l1 | grep "PhysMem"` and post the output

Comment: You do not need `grep` and `awk`, use: `top -l1 | awk '/PhysMem/ {print "X"int(($2+$4)/($8+$10)*50)"X"}'`  (does not solve your problem)

Comment: I posted the output for `top -l1 | grep "PhysMem"` in the original post, Fredrik.

Comment: `$8` and `$10` is non existence and give `0`, so dividing on `0` gives error. What do you like to calculate out from your output? `$2=6796M` `$4=(936M` as you see, not clean numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaning your solution by removing unneeded parentheses and `int`

```
top -l1 | awk '/PhysMem/ {print int((1-$6/($2+$6))*50)}'
42
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

```
top -l 1 | awk '/PhysMem/ {print $4}' | sed s/M// | sed s/\(//
```

Used memory:

```
top -l 1 | awk '/PhysMem/ {print $2}
```

Free memory:

```
top -l 1 | awk '/PhysMem/ {print $6}
```

Answer (score 0):

This achieves the result I was looking for.

```
top -l1 |awk '/PhysMem/ {print "X"int((1-(int($6)/((int($6)+int($2)))))*50)"X"}'
```

For anyone's interest and some context, I was trying to convert this CPU geeklet to Memory geeklet:
http://freshmacapps.com/geektool-scripts/geektool-cpu-circle-monitor

Thank you very much to everyone who contributed.